# How can I send GridView to Printer in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I send GridView to Printer in C#

Answer (score 2):

A DataGridView is a Control. There is no Print function available for it to my knowledge.

You'll need to take the data and format it in a Report (using something like Crystal Reports or Microsoft Reporting Services).

EDIT: Here's a bit more information about how to do it: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/dc9d3acf-ccf8-457f-ba31-ef09fb357aee

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a combination of the `PrintDocument` class and your `DataGridView`'s `DrawToBitmap(...)` method:

```
using System.Drawing.Printing;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PrintDocument printer = new PrintDocument();
    printer.PrintPage += printer_PrintPage;
    printer.Print();
}
void printer_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(dataGridView1.Width, 
        dataGridView1.Height))
    {
        dataGridView1.DrawToBitmap(bmp,
            new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height));
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0);
    }
    e.HasMorePages = false;
}
```

This may not be exactly what you need, however, since this will print the `DataGridView` exactly as it looks on your form (i.e. with scrollbars visible and much of your data not visible).